# How to receive socket events inside a flutterBackgroundServices method [FLUTTER]

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io, background-process

I am using a server in node js to run socket.io, what i want to do is that when the app is in the background it still receive events from the sockets, can only send events, but does not receive them.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  socketConnection.socket.connect();
  await FlutterBackgroundService.initialize(onStart); //here start executing the onStart method
  runApp(MyApp());
}


onStart() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  if (await service.isServiceRunning()) {
    socketEvents();//socket events method
  }
}

socketEvents() {
  log(socketConnection.socket.connected.toString()); //here I want to know if it is connected and it always shows me **false**, but it does connect
  socketConnection.socket.on('noty_event', (data) async {
    log(data['msg'].toString()); //I want to show in the console when an event arrives but it does not show anything
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, somebody has already find a solution for this problem?